# None of my onclick/mouse over events fire once I add an addeventlistener to my code

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

All of my events work until I add the addeventlistener at the bottom of my .js file. I'm new to programming and trying to understand addeventlisteners, and even when I follow youtube tutorials they aren't working, so I'm at a loss right now.

I've been watching [Nazmus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KalCLrNDdoM&index=30&list=PLqrMhnVdq86RWkt5p2lJq8XTe9JfD5vd5) and even this format of typing an addeventlistener nothing fires. Also, when I comment out all of my events except for the addeventlistener it also isn't firing.

Javascript & HTML:

```js
document.getElementById(firstp)
firstp.onmouseover = function () {
firstp.innerHTML = "Oops."
}

document.getElementById("name").onclick = function (){
  var name = prompt("Enter your name");
    document.getElementById("outputName").innerText = name;
}

document.getElementById("city").onclick = function (){
  var city = prompt("Enter your city");
    document.getElementById("outputCity").innerText = city;
}

document.getElementById("changeGreen").onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById("outputName").style.color = 'green';
    document.getElementById("outputCity").style.color = 'green';
}

document.getElementById("changeRed").onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById("outputName").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("outputCity").style.color = 'red'; 
}

let addEvent1 = document.getElementById("addEvent1");
addEvent1.addEventListener("click",alertFunction);
function alertFunction {
    alert("Hello!");
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>longin</title>
        <link rel=stylesheet href="login.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <p id="firstp">This is a paragraph</p>

    <button id="name">Name</button> <br>
    <button id="city">City</button> <br>
    <button id="changeGreen">Change Font Color Green</button> <br>
    <button id="changeRed">Change Font Color Red</button>
    
    <p> Your name is <span id = "outputName"></span></p>
  <P>The city in which you live: <span id = "outputCity"></span></P>
    <button id ="addEvent1"> Add event listener Button 1</button>
    <button id ="addEvent2"> Add event listener Button 2</button>
    <button id ="addEvent3"> Add event listener Button 3</button>
          <script src="login.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `alertFunction` is missing brackets `()`

Answer (score 1):

All (standard) functions need their argument list enclosed in parentheses after the function name, even when the function doesn't accept any arguments (in which case the parentheses should be empty `()`). Use

```
function alertFunction() {
  alert("Hello!");
}
```

```js
document.getElementById(firstp)
firstp.onmouseover = function () {
firstp.innerHTML = "Oops."
}

document.getElementById("name").onclick = function (){
  var name = prompt("Enter your name");
    document.getElementById("outputName").innerText = name;
}

document.getElementById("city").onclick = function (){
  var city = prompt("Enter your city");
    document.getElementById("outputCity").innerText = city;
}

document.getElementById("changeGreen").onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById("outputName").style.color = 'green';
    document.getElementById("outputCity").style.color = 'green';
}

document.getElementById("changeRed").onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById("outputName").style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById("outputCity").style.color = 'red'; 
}

let addEvent1 = document.getElementById("addEvent1");
addEvent1.addEventListener("click",alertFunction);
function alertFunction() {
    alert("Hello!");
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>longin</title>
        <link rel=stylesheet href="login.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <p id="firstp">This is a paragraph</p>

    <button id="name">Name</button> <br>
    <button id="city">City</button> <br>
    <button id="changeGreen">Change Font Color Green</button> <br>
    <button id="changeRed">Change Font Color Red</button>
    
    <p> Your name is <span id = "outputName"></span></p>
  <P>The city in which you live: <span id = "outputCity"></span></P>
    <button id ="addEvent1"> Add event listener Button 1</button>
    <button id ="addEvent2"> Add event listener Button 2</button>
    <button id ="addEvent3"> Add event listener Button 3</button>
          <script src="login.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Arrow functions, once you get to them, have one exception to that rule: if there's only a single argument to the arrow function, the parentheses may be omitted:

```js
const someFn = arg => {
  console.log('someFn running with arg ' + arg);
};
someFn();
```

But otherwise, when you have zero or 2+ arguments, you always need parentheses.

Comment: Crap you beat me to it.